# How to change the title in an Electron Notification?

Tags: node.js, notifications, electron, chromium

Now I'm making windows app by using ElectronJS. After packaging app, I tested app.

But the title of notification is "Electron". How can I set the title of notification to my app name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notifications](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications) says all about it.

From main process

```
new Notification({
  title: 'My Title',
  body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
})
```

From renderer process

```
new Notification('My Title', {
  body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
})
```

Comment: The field OP is talking about is not the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use app.setAppUserModelId to define a custom id for your application.

Then use shell.writeShortcutLink to add a shortcut to the Start Menu (if one isn't there already) for your application, with the same app user model id. You only want to do this once, and preferably you'd want to do it in an installer rather than in your app, but this usable for a proof of concept.

Windows will use the shortcut's name as the notification title.

(If a shortcut cannot be found the app user model id itself will be used.)